# Laravel Model Eager loading and ordering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I'm new to Laravel and thought it be cool to purchase the Codehappy ebook by Dayle Rees.

I just finished the blog tutorial and thought a bit on how he retrieved the posts from the Post model. Coming from a .net (ASP.NET MVC) background I think it will be important to order the posts while eager loading the author.

He eager loads the model like this.

```
$posts = Post::with('author')->get();
```

My question is where can you use the "order_by" clause?
the order_by itself works when I use:

```
$posts = Post::order_by('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Regards
RaVen

Comment: Laravel on Stackexchange http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel?referrer=VUgOWgZpXyO753uZWv1VMg2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I manage to solve it by:

```
$posts = Post::with('author')->order_by('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Indeed this is the correct answer. Eloquent extends the Fluent query builder so it inherits functions like where() and order_by(). Eloquent introduces the "eager loading" feature, but is required to be the first part of the method chaining (ie the static method called first)

Comment: Laravel on Stackexchange http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel?referrer=VUgOWgZpXyO753uZWv1VMg2